# How to set translation or margin to child and avoid parent's paddings

Tags: android, padding, margin, android-constraintlayout

I need to move some layout to the area of parents paddings but the view just cutted. I was trying to set - margin for child and transition but nothing works good.

[image]

Can anybody help me with that? I'm using `ConstraintLayout` as a parent and for some reason I don't want to change it's paddings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the following on the parent:

```
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

This will allow the child to draw inside the parent's padding.